# Same H1 Tag in different pages?

Tags: html, seo

Can I use same H1 tag in all pages?
For example:

```
<header> <h1>Here is some description of the activity on the site</h1></header>
```

The code above will be the same on each page in header.php. Is it semantically correct?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is semantically correct. But Google Search Engine Optimization Guide doesn't recommend to do it.

Comment: Thank you for the rapid response!